How can you build a Flatpak package in a Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline?
I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline that builds Flatpak packages in Bitbucket CI, but I'm struggling with getting Flatpak working in the container. Initially I tried using the freedesktopsdk/flatpak:23.08 image, but installing the SDK necessary to build packages didn't work, with the only error shown being open(O_TMPFILE): No such file or directory, which I'm not sure how to deal with. The full output is as follows:
$ flatpak remote-add --user --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
$ flatpak install -y --noninteractive --user flathub org.freedesktop.Sdk//23.08
Installing runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/23.08
Installing runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/23.08-extra
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/23.08 from remote flathub: open(O_TMPFILE): No such file or directory
Installing runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/2.2.0
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/23.08-extra from remote flathub: open(O_TMPFILE): No such file or directory
Installing runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Locale/x86_64/23.08
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/2.2.0 from remote flathub: open(O_TMPFILE): No such file or directory
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Sdk.Locale: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Locale/x86_64/23.08 from remote flathub: open(O_TMPFILE): No such file or directory
Installing runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/23.08
Error: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Sdk: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/23.08 from remote flathub: open(O_TMPFILE): No such file or directory

I'm not sure how to remedy this. Despite the name, the Freedesktop SDK does not seem to come preinstalled as a Flatpak package in the Docker image as if I run flatpak-builder it complains about the 23.08 SDK not being installed. I also tried the flathub/flatpak-builder-lint package as this is what Flathub itself uses, but there must be some discrepancy elsewhere as it gives the same errors as shown above.
How can I successfully build a Flatpak package in a Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline?
